# IsPost property in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I'm trying to use `IsPost` porperty in asp.net code, but I don't understand to what object this property is belonged? I'm trying to use

```
WebPageRenderingBase.IsPost
```

But the exception is raised.

Comment: If you get an exception, make sure you say what the exception is. We could have helped you much quicker if your provided the code you are using along with the exception it generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a [Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.webpages.webpagerenderingbase.ispost%28v=vs.99%29.aspx) which says,

`When overridden in a derived class, returns a value that indicates whether the HTTP data transfer method used by the client to request the Web page is POST. Returns true if the HTTP verb is "POST"; otherwise, false.`

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But I'm trying to use `System.Web.WebPages.WebPageRenderingBase.IsPost` and the same exception is raised. How to fix this?

Comment: @Dmitry Fucintv How are you using it? Can you post the code?

Comment: `if(System.Web.WebPages.WebPageRenderingBase.IsPost){message="Form submitted";}`

Comment: I've understood this problem. I'm trying to get nonstatic property by static way.

Comment: @DmitryFucintv Thanks for letting me know about the actual problem. :)